# Jquery form submit with id, serializeArray cant get input data

Tags: jquery

I have a `form` with an id being submit, but `serializeArray` cant get the input data. Why?

```js
$(document).on('submit', $('#abc')[0], function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var d = $(this).serializeArray();
  console.log(d);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="abc">
  <input type="number" name="min">
</form>
```

Comment: See [*Direct and delegated event handlers*](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you're passing an Element object as the second argument of a delegated event handler. The correct delegated event handler method signature is expecting a string selector:

```js
$(document).on('submit', '#abc', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var d = $(this).serializeArray();
  console.log(d);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="abc">
  <input type="number" name="min">
</form>
```